# FFMPEG "buffer queue overflow, dropping" with trim and atrim filters

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

In FFMPEG I am actually trimming and concating a 24 FPS video. When I apply a complex filter

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]setpts = PTS-STARTPTS[bv];
  [bv]split=6[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5];
  [v0]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=142,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[0v];
  [v1]trim=start_frame=846:end_frame=878,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[1v];
  [v2]trim=start_frame=57:end_frame=114,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[2v];
  [v3]trim=start_frame=865:end_frame=885,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[3v];
  [v4]trim=start_frame=70:end_frame=155,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[4v];
  [v5]trim=start_frame=155:end_frame=909,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[5v];
  [0:a]asplit=6[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5];
  [a0]atrim=0.041666666666666664:5.917,asetpts=N/SR/TB[0a];
  [a1]atrim=35.256:36.603,asetpts=N/SR/TB[1a];
  [a2]atrim=2.379:4.767,asetpts=N/SR/TB[2a];
  [a3]atrim=36.024:36.859,asetpts=N/SR/TB[3a];
  [a4]atrim=2.93:6.438172,asetpts=N/SR/TB[4a];
  [a5]atrim=6.438172:37.895,asetpts=N/SR/TB[5a];
  [0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a][3v][3a][4v][4a][5v][5a]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1[vv][aa]"\
  -map "[vv]" -map "[aa]" output.mp4
```

I am getting "buffer queue overflow, dropping" error. The resultant video and audio is still and not working properly.

```
ffmpeg version 3.2-1~16.04.york1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-3ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1york0) 20161019
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-libtesseract --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-openal --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-chromaprint --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    track           : 0
    artist          : 
    album           : 
    date            : 0
    genre           : 
    lyrics          : 
    title           : 
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:37.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 951 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 820 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    track           : 0
    artist          : 
    album           : 
    date            : 0
    genre           : 
    lyrics          : 
    title           : 
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setpts
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> asplit
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_concat_33 @ 0x55650097b420] Buffer queue overflow, dropping. 471.5kbits/s speed=4.94x    
    Last message repeated 201 times
[Parsed_concat_33 @ 0x55650097b420] Buffer queue overflow, dropping. 522.9kbits/s speed=3.89x    
    Last message repeated 1266 times
[Parsed_concat_33 @ 0x55650097b420] Buffer queue overflow, dropping. 557.0kbits/s speed=3.28x    
    Last message repeated 48 times
[output stream 0:1 @ 0x556500947e20] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:1, something may be wrong.
[Parsed_concat_33 @ 0x55650097b420] Buffer queue overflow, dropping. 718.6kbits/s speed=3.46x    
    Last message repeated 19 times
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x5565009785c0] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
frame= 1091 fps=117 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2795kB time=00:00:45.51 bitrate= 503.1kbits/s dup=475 drop=0 speed=4.88x    
video:2455kB audio:316kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.861779%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] frame I:8     Avg QP:19.26  size: 24207
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] frame P:409   Avg QP:21.33  size:  4108
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] frame B:674   Avg QP:27.46  size:   949
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] consecutive B-frames: 10.3% 13.9% 24.5% 51.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] mb I  I16..4:  9.9% 57.0% 33.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] mb P  I16..4:  3.6%  7.6%  2.9%  P16..4: 33.0% 10.6%  3.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:39.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.8%  0.4%  B16..8: 24.5%  2.6%  0.2%  direct: 0.5%  skip:70.5%  L0:55.5% L1:41.8% BI: 2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] 8x8 transform intra:53.8% inter:66.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.6% 50.0% 14.8% inter: 6.2% 7.7% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 28% 17% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 23% 28%  3%  4%  3% 11%  3%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 26% 16%  2%  5%  3% 16%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] i8c dc,h,v,p: 60% 22% 13%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] ref P L0: 72.6%  8.4% 15.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] ref B L0: 88.5% 10.7%  0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] ref B L1: 93.3%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55650097a540] kb/s:442.30
[aac @ 0x556500979280] Qavg: 3215.870
```

I tried with other stackoverflow questions but none of them worked. Also I think it is partially because the trim timings are mixed. That is start time can be anywhere between 0-end. When I make it strictly increasing it is working fine.

Comment: Your CLI snippet helped me very much with my case. I'm just curious why you added `loop=1:1:1` filter, I don't understand how it affects the result.

Answer (score 15):

Add a fifo filter at the end of each of the video filterchains.

i.e.

```
[v0]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=142,loop=1:1:1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,fifo[0v];
```

Although probably not necessary, you can add `afifo` to the end of audio chains as well.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But couldn't understand why it worked. Can you explain the phenomena ?

Comment: ffmpeg works with time-based media files, and its filters don't wait forever if some part of the fiiltergraph is slow - frames get dropped if the next filter doesn't request frames fast enough. `fifo` is a `first in first out` buffer for video (afifo for audio). With this filter, frames are held till passed on to next filter.

Comment: worked like a charm, `afifo` was necesary